# Boost syslog to a specific file using syslog sink

Tags: c++, logging, boost

Is it possible to configure boost log to send logs to a specific file when using the syslog backend on debian9. The following code initializes my logging sink:

```
namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
using namespace boost::log::sinks::syslog;

boost::shared_ptr< logging::core > core = logging::core::get();

boost::shared_ptr< sinks::syslog_backend > backend =
    boost::make_shared< sinks::syslog_backend >(
        keywords::use_impl = sinks::syslog::udp_socket_based,
        keywords::facility = sinks::syslog::local0
    );


// Create and fill in another level translator for "MyLevel" attribute of type string
sinks::syslog::custom_severity_mapping< std::string > mapping("MyLevel");
mapping["debug"] = sinks::syslog::debug;
mapping["info"] = sinks::syslog::info;
mapping["warning"] = sinks::syslog::warning;
mapping["error"] = sinks::syslog::error;
backend->set_severity_mapper(mapping);
backend->set_target_address("localhost");

// Wrap it into the frontend and register in the core.
// The backend requires synchronization in the frontend.
typedef sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::syslog_backend > sink_t;
boost::shared_ptr< sink_t > sink(new sink_t(backend));

core->add_sink(sink);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syslog API (and protocol) doesn't allow applications to specify the way how logs are processed by the log server. For that you have to configure your syslog server. See the documentation for your server (e.g. [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/), [syslog-ng](https://syslog-ng.org/) or [journald](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html) for logging through the syslog API).

If you really want to configure the target file name in your application then you have to write the file from the application. The [`text_file_backend`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html#log.detailed.sink_backends.text_file) sink backend will help you do that.